# "БашкИ" или "бОшки"?

Tags: орфоэпия, словоизменение

На Грамоте написано, что множественное число от слова "башка" "башк**и**". Это очень странно, я всегда слышал, что говорят *"б**о**шки".* Как же всё-таки правильно-то, а точнее, как говорить лучше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интересный вопрос, занимался я с ним. Словари правы абсолютно. Если кратко, в современном русском вариант с заменой корневой гласной при образовании падежных или числовых форм  не прокатывает. Так что "бошки"  может быть только в народной речи, в силу фонетического восприятия "башка" как акающего от "бошка". А далее по модели: рук**а** - р**у**ки, ног**а** - н**о**ги. Или просторечного кишк**а** - к**и**шки  (нормативно - кишк**и**). Но первопричина все-таки в нечеткости гласного в языках-источниках.  В тюркских можно воспринять и как А, так и О.

Comment: Интересно, спасибо!!! А "п**о**льта" по другой аналогии говорят? И ещё мне нравится говорить н**о**лито.))

Comment: Почему по другой? Та же в общем-то схема с просторечной заменой гласного под ударением. Только там еще и ошибка в том, что самостоятельной формы для множественного числа нет вовсе.  Вот "нолито" - это уже из серии (?)угл**у**бить и (?)н**а**чать.  Вообще ничем не мотивировано. Хотя, согласен, некоторый шарм в этом есть. Гусарский, что ли.